# externally sourced text inserted into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to add text from an external .txt file to a div within my website and format it to a header and then text, there will also be a picture, similar to a news story. Thank you.

There will be three stories in 3 seperate divs within a holding div. My coding for the divs is below. I have tried to do research into this but can not seem to find a way within my realm of knowledge to implement this.

```
<article>
    <img src="slide1.png" alt="slide 1" width="980" height="550" />
    <div class="contents">
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
            <div style="float: left; background-color: yellow; text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                50%
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 25%;">
            <div style="background-color: red; text-align: center;">
                25%
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: blue; text-align: center;">
                25%
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try an iframe ?

Comment: Do it using jquery load function.

Comment: See http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/fopen-fread-reading-entire-external-file-83103.html#post369650 , they appear to have found the solution

Comment: @RohitBatham could you show me how to use the jquery load function in this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
   $('div').load('textfile.txt');
})
```

Comment: Try to also provide with some textual explanation on what your code does